# Fetching phone number from a list of string in python as format is not same for every record

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to fetch phone numbers from these rows, the problem is since there is no defined format hence I couldn't use a static regex on it. I tried catching the numbers between the keywords Tel.: and Fax, it worked but the same logic anyway will not work for all of them. Is there any possible way through which we can target and fetch all these phone numbers together?

-Data

1."Lohas Living Inc James Mazzello US 845 3RD Ave Fl 6 New York NY 10022-6630 +1208-964-6807  Email Address:jadgemaello@gmail.com James Mazzello  US 845 3RD Ave Fl 6 New York NY 10022-6630 +1208-964-6807 EIN: 30-0961431 "

2.Herzlich Willkommen im Amazon Shop von 1a-Handelsagentur. Für Fragen stehen wir Ihnen gerne unter der 039932-829721 zur Verfügung. 1a-handelsagentur.de Andre Burmeister
Lindenallee 2 17213 Malchow Kontakt Tel.: 039932 - 829721 Fax.: 039932 – 81417

3.An der Bundesstrasse 26 33829 Borgholzhausen Deutschland Telefon: 015140008562 E-Mail: webmaster@9pm-store.de USt-IdNr.: DE215752000 Wir sind seit 01.08.2015".

4.Lohas Living Inc James Mazzello US 845 3RD Ave Fl 6 New York NY 10022-6630 +1208-964-6807 Email Address:jadgemaello@gmail.com

5.TiTo:direkt Vertriebs GmbH & Co. KG &br; Speckmannstr. 45&br; 28879 Grasberg&br; Deutschland &br; &br; Tel.: 04298 / 401-294&br; Fax: 04298 / 401-329&br; E-Mail: amazon@tito-buerobedarf.de &br;

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the data you showed above, all phone or fax numbers are either prefaced by a `+`, `Tel.:`, `Telefon:`, or `Fax:` label.  Given that, we can phrase a regex as follows:

```py
inp = """1."Lohas Living Inc James Mazzello US 845 3RD Ave Fl 6 New York NY 10022-6630 +1208-964-6807 Email Address:jadgemaello@gmail.com James Mazzello US 845 3RD Ave Fl 6 New York NY 10022-6630 +1208-964-6807 EIN: 30-0961431 "

2.Herzlich Willkommen im Amazon Shop von 1a-Handelsagentur. Für Fragen stehen wir Ihnen gerne unter der 039932-829721 zur Verfügung. 1a-handelsagentur.de Andre Burmeister Lindenallee 2 17213 Malchow Kontakt Tel.: 039932 - 829721 Fax.: 039932 - 81417

3.An der Bundesstrasse 26 33829 Borgholzhausen Deutschland Telefon: 015140008562 E-Mail: webmaster@9pm-store.de USt-IdNr.: DE215752000 Wir sind seit 01.08.2015".

4.Lohas Living Inc James Mazzello US 845 3RD Ave Fl 6 New York NY 10022-6630 +1208-964-6807 Email Address:jadgemaello@gmail.com

5.TiTo:direkt Vertriebs GmbH & Co. KG &br; Speckmannstr. 45&br; 28879 Grasberg&br; Deutschland &br; &br; Tel.: 04298 / 401-294&br; Fax: 04298 / 401-329&br; E-Mail: amazon@tito-buerobedarf.de &br;"""

numbers = re.findall(r'(?:\+|\bTel\.?:|\bFax\.?:|\bTelefon:)\s*(\d+(?:[ ]*[/-][ ]*\d+)*)', inp)
print(numbers)
```

This prints:

```
['1208-964-6807', '1208-964-6807', '039932 - 829721', '039932 - 81417',
 '015140008562', '1208-964-6807', '04298 / 401-294', '04298 / 401-329']
```